# LinkButton.Command in user control (ascx) will not call specified method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code:

```
   public partial class queryTerm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private static readonly List<string> BooleanOperators = new List<string> { ".", "AND", "AND NOT", "OR", "OR NOT" };

        protected void BuildBoolPanel()
        {
            var parensOpen = _labelBoolean.Text;
            foreach (var @operator in BooleanOperators)
            {
                if (parensOpen == @operator)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var linkButton = new LinkButton();
                linkButton.Text = @operator;
                linkButton.CommandArgument = @operator;
                linkButton.CommandName = "parensOpen";
                linkButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(linkButton_Command);
                _popupMenuParensOpen.Controls.Add(linkButton);
                var literalLineBreak = new Literal();
                literalLineBreak.Text = "<BR/>";
                _popupMenuParensOpen.Controls.Add(literalLineBreak);
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
                BuildBoolPanel();
        }

        void linkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            _labelBoolean.Text = (string)e.CommandArgument;
            BuildBoolPanel();
        }
    }
```

I have a panel(it's _popupMenuParensOpen) that is shown with the hoverextender whenever the cursor finds itself over a specific label in my user control.

This panel has all the boolean operators and '.' meaning not set.
I programatically add the boolean operators as a label in my panel, and I only add those that don't match what it is currently set to. For instance if my label is set to 'AND', when I hover over it, I display everything but 'AND'.

The problem is these never call linkButton_Command even though I instruct them to.
Weirder yet, if I remove the 'if (!this.IsPostBack) in page load, it will call it.

My control is inside an updatePanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're dynamically adding the controls during the Page_Load event.  When a postback occurs those controls aren't going to exist and will need to be created every time.  This is why when you remove your *if (!Page.IsPostBack)*, and the controls are rebuilt, it works.

Since you're building this as a user control, you might want to look in to overriding the [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) method.